# AS3: Checking if a variable is of the Object type

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to do something like this in Actionscript 3:

```
if(variable is Object) ...;
else ...;
```

Where `variable` could be a `String()`, `Number()`, `Array()`, `Object()`...

Currently the above check returns true for all of these types, which makes sense. I only want it to return true for objects made with `new Object()`, however.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should try to use this functions - `getQualifiedClassName` and `typeof`. Here's a code showing how they behave for different data types you've listed, see the difference for the Array and Numbers especially:

**Code:**

```
var o = new Array();                
trace ("var o = new Array()");
trace (getQualifiedClassName(o));
trace (typeof(o));      
var o = new Object();   
trace ("var o = new Object();");
trace (getQualifiedClassName(o));
trace (typeof(o));
var o = new String();
trace ("var o = new String()");
trace (getQualifiedClassName(o));
trace (typeof(o));
var o = new Number()
trace ("var o = new Number()");
trace (getQualifiedClassName(o));
trace (typeof(o));              
var o = 3.14;
trace ("var o = 3.14");
trace (getQualifiedClassName(o));
trace (typeof(o));
```

Result:

```
var o = new Array()
Array
object
var o = new Object();
Object
object
var o = new String()
String
string
var o = new Number()
int
number
var o = 3.14
Number
number
```

I assume getQualifiedClassName would be what you're looking for, which is in the flash utils package:

```
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
```

Comment: Yep, I actually found out about getQualifiedClassName shortly after, and it is indeed what I was looking for. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 5):

Try something based around one of these:

```
if (variable.constructor.toString().match(/object/i) == 'Object')

if (variable.constructor.toString().indexOf("Object") != -1)
```

If the object is an Object() the constructor string will be something like

```
function Object() { ... }
```

so you can check for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `getQualifiedSuperclassName` which returns `null` for the `Object` type as it doesn't have a super class:

```
public static function isObject( obj:* ):Boolean
{
    if ( obj == null )
        return false;
    return ( getQualifiedSuperclassName( obj ) == null );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here you go, try this..

```
var ob:Object = new Object();

trace(ob); //[object Object]
trace(typeof(ob) == "object"); //true

if(typeof(ob) == "object"){
    //true
}else{
    //false
}
```